# ¿Cómo es la consulta para mostrar el stock actual de un inventario?

Tags: php, mysql

Ando haciendo un programa para la tesis en `php`. Se trata de administrar cuentas, clientes y productos. Pero tengo un inconveniente de cómo realizar la parte de inventarios.

Me explico, quiero que el inventario me muestre el estado actual de un producto.

Lo que necesito es hacer una consulta que me genere el informe de control de stock, es decir, de cada producto sumar la cantidad de entradas y restar la cantidad de salida.

la base de datos la tengo así:

[image: base datos]

para listar en inventario los artículos lo tengo así:

```
$sql="select articulo.art_nombre, articulo.art_categoria, articulo.art_color, inventario.cantidad, inventario.descripcion from articulo, inventario WHERE articulo.id_articulo=inventario.articulo";
```

para agregar una entrada, me envía a un formulario y la consulta la tengo así:

```
$sql="select articulo.art_nombre, articulo.art_categoria, articulo.art_color, inventario.cantidad, inventario.descripcion from articulo, inventario WHERE articulo.id_articulo=inventario.articulo";

$inventario = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

después de haber ingresado los datos al formulario lo valido con el siguiente código:

```
require "conexion_datos.php";

$cantidad = $_POST['cantidad'];
$articulo = $_POST['articulo'];

$entrada="INSERT INTO entradas (cantidad, articulo,) values ('".$cantidad."','".$articulo."')";

$resultado=$mysqli->query($entrada);

$actualizar="UPDATE inventario SET cantidad = cantidad + '$_REQUEST[cantidad]' WHERE inventario.articulo='$_REQUEST[articulo]' ";

$inventario = $mysqli->query($actualizar);

if ($resultado) {

    header ("location: inventario.php?x=5"); //x=5 se agregado correctamente

} else {

    header ("location: inventario.php?x=6"); //x=6 problemas al agregar la entrada

}
```

Pero cuando envío los datos me sale "problema al agregar la entrada".

Comment: Aunque no tiene nada que ver con tu pregunta, viendo tu diseño, creo que te falta la relación de la factura con el resto de las tablas, para poder sacarlas bien, ya que una factura es para un cliente (no tienes la relación) y tiene productos (que tampoco tienen relación con las tablas)

Comment: Si  es que todavía no he realizado esa relación y lo de "productos" lo tengo como articulo, si puedes me das una orientación de como debe ir relacionado la factura se le agradecería.

Comment: dos preguntas ¿los valores que envías por POST si te están llegando?
¿qué errores te manda? podrías hacer un print_r() a los valores y a la sentencia update podría ser que está tratando de realizar una entrada o actualizar el inventario de un artículo que no existe

Comment: Has intentado utilizar `print mysqli_error($con);` para ver el error que te dá Mysql?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un error en el `insert`, te sobra una coma en la lista de parámetros:

```
$entrada = "INSERT INTO entradas (cantidad, articulo,) values ('".$cantidad."', '".$articulo."')";
                                                    ^
                                                    └ esta coma sobra
```

Eso hace que la consulta falle y por eso `$resultado` es `false`, y en la sentencia condicional siempre se irá por el lado del error. Debería ser así:

```
$entrada = "INSERT INTO entradas (cantidad, articulo) values ('".$cantidad."','".$articulo."')";
```

Comment: Gracias, lo modifique pero igual no me deja insertar en la tabla entrada.

Answer (score 1):

Veo dos pequeñas cosas en tú código.

La primera es el INSERT, prueba con este código

```
$entrada="INSERT INTO entradas (cantidad, articulo) values ('".$cantidad."','".$articulo."')";
```

Al poner la "," en el listado de valores a insertar, el sql, está esperando un valor, que luego en la lista de parámetros no le pasas

El segundo es la forma de tratar el stock. Por la consulta que haces es sumar a lo que ya tienes, la cantidad de productos que te han comprado, cuando para la gestión de stock, lo normal es hacerlo al revés,almacenar la cantidad total de productos que tienes y restar lo que vendes (aunque existen muchas maneras de gestionar el sctock y estoy seguro que si lo haces así es porque te funciona correctamente)

Answer (score 1):

Aparte de la coma que esta de mas:

```
$entrada="INSERT INTO entradas (cantidad, articulo,) values ('".$cantidad."','".$articulo."')";
```

La tabla `entradas` tiene `FK` `usuario`, valida si es un campo obligatorio, por si fuese necesario revisa también los otros campos (fecha, id_entrada).
Asi deberias considerar un `INSERT` con todos los campos obligatorios:

```
//agregar usuario
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];    
$entrada="INSERT INTO entradas (usuario, cantidad, articulo) values ('"$usuario"','".$cantidad."','".$articulo."')";
```

Answer (score -1):

**Consulta de Stock.**
armas una consulta de entradas a stock agrupada por producto y las cantidades las ingresas en una variable entradas y reservas una variable 0 as salidas
armas una consulta de salidas de stock agrupada por producto y las cantidades las ingresas a una variable salidas reservando una variable 0 as entradas (en el mismo orden claro) . Realizas UNION ALL de las dos consultas y con ellas haces una consulta derivada o Subconsulta en la que tomas los productos y directamente haces la resta de (entradas - salidas) as stock

Comment: Por favor brinda un ejemplo de lo que estás explicando aquí.